# C# Dapper using JSON_VALUE for SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, t-sql, dapper, sql-server-2016, json-query

I want to query data from my table using `JSON_VALUE`:

```
var str = "123";
var value = "Name"
using(var conn = GetMyConnection())
{
   var result = conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>(
      @"SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
         WHERE JSON_VALUE([JsonColumn], @MyQuery) = @Str",
      new
      {
         MyQuery = $"$.{value}",
         Str = str
      }
   );
}
```

I try this in SQL Server, it is working:

```
SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([JsonColumn], '$.Name') = '123'
```

How should I adjust my code?

Comment: I suggest you create a Stored Procedure and Give away your json string as a parameter and handle it there.

Comment: I tried this code on my local environment. And it works correctly. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: @sarslan It won't work because OP pass it as literal, while in C# he tries to pass it as variable. Only way in SQL Server is to use dynamic SQL or build query string in C# code.

Comment: @lad2025 Actualy, I tried it with Azure Sql and it worked. You will be right, because I did not try it with sql 2016.

Comment: @sarslan As in my answer `In SQL Server 2017 and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path.`  Azure is always ahead that on-premise :)

Answer (score 9):

> I try this in SQL Server, it working

First of all you miss one important thing `variable` vs `literal`.

It won't work on `SQL Server 2016` when used in SSMS:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTAble(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), JsonColumn NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO MyTable( JsonColumn)
VALUES('{"Name":123}');


-- it will work
SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([JsonColumn], '$.Name') = '123';

-- let''s try your example
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX) = '$.Name';
SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([JsonColumn], @Path) = '123';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=89795ded27ec1122a9061d249ad81860)**

You will get:

> **The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.**

---

Second from `SQL Server 2017+` you could pass path as variable. From [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql):

> **path**
>
> A JSON path that specifies the property to extract. For more
>   info, see JSON Path Expressions (SQL Server).
>
> **In SQL Server 2017 and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a
>   variable as the value of path.**

**[DbFiddle Demo 2017](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89795ded27ec1122a9061d249ad81860)**

---

And finally to get it work on `SQL Server 2016` you may build your query string using concatenation (instead of parameter binding).

Warning! This could lead to serious security problem and SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Just a note if somebody's having these issues: I also got this error on SQL Server 2016 even though I was actually using a string literal. The issue was that I was using forced parameterization. So the solution for me was to temporarily switch to simple parametrization, run the query, and then switch to forced parametrization again.

Comment: @TomPažourek Great observation.