# Update an existing JSON value inside a JSON Array in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update an existing JSON value inside a JSON array. I can append a new JSON to the JSON array using `JSON_MODIFY`. Suppose i have a JSON like :

```
[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"peter"}]
```

But i want to update only the json with id=102.

Is it possible using `JSON_MODIFY()`?

**EDIT**:

Actual data

```
{"Details":{"SId":{"Type":"string","Value":"1234"},"BookList":{"Type":"List","Value":[{"id": "101", "name": "Book1"},{"id": "102", "name": "Book2"}]},"SName":{"Type":"string","Value":"john"}}}
```

Comment: Please do not ever edit question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you need to add some details mark it clearly or ask new question

Answer (score 23):

You could use `CTE` to parse it and combine path in `UPDATE` part:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM t
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c) s
  WHERE i = 1
    AND JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.id')=102
)
UPDATE cte
SET c = JSON_MODIFY(c, '$[' + cte.[key] + '].name', 'Joe');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b0f6e2e2e7f442cc95adb7f2f8e2730d)**

Output:

```
-- Before
[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"peter"}]

-- After
[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"Joe"}]
```

This will work on SQL Server 2017+ or SQL Azure DB otherwise you will get error. [More info about path literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860751/c-sharp-dapper-using-json-value-for-sql-server-2016)

Comment: I have given my actual json format.How can i use cte and cross aply there?

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution that works in versions below SQL Server 2017? i'm getting `The argument 2 of the "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal.` error.

Comment: @Jishad, you could generate your update statements. Something like `select 'update [yourtable] set [jsoncol] = json_modify([jsoncol], ''$[' + [key] + '].name'', ''Joe'') where id = ' + [yourtable].id from [yourtable] cross apply openjson([jsoncol])` and then execute them all with sp_executesql (of course, being wary of sql injection)

Comment: Wouldn't believe how hard I've hunted for this answer, much love

Answer (score 1):

Updating JSON Data (Postgresql)

If the column in your table contains json data and you want to update this data, you can use the following structure:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = '{"key" : value}'::jsonb 
WHERE column_name::jsonb @> '{“new_key” : new_value}'::jsonb;
```

Note: Usually @> is used as the "contains" operator.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to generate the statement like this:

- In this way you, won't get the error of "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between `Latin1_General_BIN` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`"
- Also, you won't get this error "The argument 2 of the `JSON_MODIFY` must be a string literal"

  ```
  WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
    t.PrimaryKey,
    JSON_VALUE([value], '$.id') as id,
    t.JsonColumn,
    o.*
    ,('UPDATE MyTable set JsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn, ''$['+[key]+'].id'', ''NewVALUE'') WHERE PrimaryKey = '''+t.PrimaryKey COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS+ '''') as statement
    FROM MyTable t
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(JsonColumn, '$')) o WHERE  JSON_VALUE(o.value, '$.Id')= 1
     )
  select * from cte;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
Declare @Input nvarchar(max) = N'[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"peter"}]';
Declare @UpdatedItem nvarchar(max) = N'{"id":"102","name":"peter1"}'

SET @Input = JSON_MODIFY(@Input, CONCAT('$[', (SELECT [Key] FROM OPENJSON(@Input) as I WHERE JSON_VALUE(I.Value,'$.id') = "102"), ']'), JSON_QUERY(@UpdatedItem));
```