# The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-value

I am passing this JSON to a stored procedure in SQL Server

```
{
    "individual": [
        {
            "app_id": 1057029,
            "size": 2
        },
        {
            "app_id": 1057053,
            "size": 3
        },
        {
            "app_id": 1057048,
            "size": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

In the stored procedure I am extracting values of `app_id` and `size` as under

```
SET @len = JSON_VALUE(@json, CONCAT('$.individual[', @i, '].size'));
SET @appId = JSON_VALUE(@json, CONCAT('$.individual[', @i, '].app_id'));
```

(Here `i` is index variable incrementing in a loop)

This works perfect on Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (version 14.0.1000.169)

But on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (version 13.0.4604.0) I am getting error:

> JSON_Value error: The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY"
> must be a string literal

Please note this is not duplicate as I already have referred questions below on SO but still didn't get solution.

[JSON_Value error: The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500764/json-value-error-the-argument-2-of-the-json-value-or-json-query-must-be-a-str)

[SQL Sever 2016 - Inconsistent Behavior - The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144153/sql-sever-2016-inconsistent-behavior-the-argument-2-of-the-json-value-or-js)

**Update**
**Why this is not duplicate question?**

None of the other questions discusses the issue in clear precise way. They have mentioned specifics instead. Rather in this question, I have mentioned use of variable `@i` which is precisely causing this error. *`JSON_VALUE` works in MSSQL2016 but it doesn't support variables as second param, that precisely is the problem here.* As a workaround, we've to use `OPENJSON` but again writing OPENJSON query to get record of particular index from json is tricky. None of the answers to other similar questions discusses this clearly. I am going to write an answer in some time demonstrating it all.

Comment: It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that this won't work on 2016: *"In SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path."* Why not switch to `OPENJSON` like the linked questions suggest? You say this isn't a duplicate, but the second link appears to be exactly the answer you want/need. If it isn't a duplicate, explain why.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for comment but not sure how to do using `OPENJSON` Can you please give brief answer? Would be really great.

Comment: @Larnu  Updated the question mentioning why this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example demonstrates the use of OpenJson for your JSON and desired query. I've never used OpenJson but found the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) more than adequate. In the last SELECT in this example, the app_id and size are columns in a table with each value pair as a row. Now you don't have to loop through an array; you now have a standard table to work with.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "individual": [
        {
            "app_id": 1057029,
            "size": 2
        },
        {
            "app_id": 1057053,
            "size": 3
        },
        {
            "app_id": 1057048,
            "size": 1
        }
    ]
}';

SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json);
SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json, '$.individual');

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.individual')
WITH (  
    app_id int,
    size int
) as apps
;
```

The output:

[image]